# "Internal Server Error" when trying to authenticate via passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, passport.js, passport-facebook

**What I want**

Okay, I have a little personal blog I am developing for a hobby of mine so I am not a professional programmer. I want to allow users to login to my web app via passport-facebook but it's a bit intimidating. Thankfully, [the git repository for this node package](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook) has a link to [an example of passport-facebook for express environments](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example).

I'm trying to run this example on heroku but I can't get it to work. I should note that in the server.js file I edited lines 16 and 17 to:

```
passport.use(new Strategy({
clientID: "my actual id value from the Facebook developer site",
clientSecret: "my actual secret from the Facebook developer site",
```

**What happens**

I get a blank screen that simply says "Internal server error" when I click on the login link. Please see the image:

[image: Error message]

Presumably the OAuth redirect URI is correct, because if it's altered in any way I get a different error as can be seen below. In fact I am convinced that the redirect URI has been successfully white listed because the first time I ran the app Facebook did popup and say an app wanted access as expected.

[image]

So I believe I have the correct redirect URI which is *https://agile-thicket-43367.herokuapp.com/return*.

**My request**

Could someone either read the [git repository I linked for passport-facebook with express](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example) and just glance at the code for any potential errors or could someone try cloning it and running it on Heroku and tell me how it goes on their end? I'm kind of stumped here as it's something that has been updated in the past month so I doubt it's out of date and it doesn't seem too complex to get it up and running.

On the Facebook developer side of things, I just added my app domain, website domain, the Facebook login product and OAuth redirect URI. I didn't change any other settings.

Comment: "Could someone either read the git repository I linked for passport-facebook with express and just glance at the code for any potential errors or could someone try cloning it and running it on Heroku and tell me how it goes on their end?" No, we're not going to do that. That's not how Stack Overflow works. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. We're here to answer focused, concrete questions, not to dig through your code and look for possible errors.

Comment: [Internal Server Error / HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The internal server error means your Heroku server is running into an error while loading. If you look at the server logs, it will give you a description of the error it is running into when trying to initially load your application.

Using the Heroku command line tools, you can simply type `heroku logs` and it will show you the last 100 lines which should contain your error.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Note that you may need to configure your application's logs to show up here. Print them to `stderr` or `stdout` and they'll be included in Heroku's main log stream.